# PHP foreach echo as soon as image has loaded

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I currently have some php code which gets the thumbnail of random Wordpress posts but the problem is when I run it none of the images show until every image has been downloaded. I was wondering if there is a way to echo the image then go to the next one. Thanks.

```
 <?php
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 25, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
                    $rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
                    <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?>
                    <li id="photo-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="visible scroll-content-item ui-widget-header"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img width="80" height="80" src="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="attachment-small-grid wp-post-image" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a> </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP cannot tell you when an image has downloaded, as it is a server side language. You have to use javascript to write code based on browser based events, like images loading.

www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/

That jQuery plugin will let you execute functions based on *each* image loading, and then on *all* images loading... I might start there.

Comment: Ah okay, I was just thinking and I noticed that its downloading full size images when it only needs 80x80 so I will fix that which should speed it up.